# When is 'isRunningInStoreDemoMode' true?

Tags: ios, iphone-privateapi, kiosk-mode

I am looking for a solution to present apps on trade shows.

I know you can install a profile to your device with the undocumented `com.apple.defaults.managed` payload to disable the home button of the device. This is a nice way to present your app on trade shows. However, sometimes you have features that shouldn't be activated on such shows or some kind of data shouldn't be stored on the device during this demo mode.

As the key you enable through this mobileconfig files is `SBStoreDemoAppLock` I thought this would also make the private `+[UIApplication isRunningInStoreDemoMode]` return `YES` but this isn't the case. Does anybody know under which circumstances this method will return YES?

I know this is private API but this is code that is only ment to be in beta distribution, so it isn't important. So please don't comment and tell my that I will be rejected by apple!

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**isRunningInStoreDemoMode**

I took a look in UIKit. What it does in this function is:

CFPreferencesGetAppBooleanValue("StoreDemoMode", "com.apple.demo-settings', &value);

I grep the binaries and saw that it's used in quite a lot of places. However, I didn't find any code where it's set. (Potentially, I could be wrong about this, because I spend quite small amount of time on it and I grep through Simulator binaries, which are different from real device binaries).

Also, it couldn't be set through com.apple.defaults.managed (only limited set of settings could be set this way).

So, my assumption is that this API could be reminiscence  of some old Kiosk mechanism which was replaced/evolved.

**Simplest way**

I think the simplest way for you would be just to have a special build for a demo, instead of trying to find a private API which will distinguish between kiosk mode and normal mode

**Guided access mode**

If you like challenges. You can take a look at new kiosk mode mechanism - Guided Access Mode.

There are two ways to enable it:
a) Through UI (https://www.appcertain.com/apple-guided-access-mode-parents/)
b) Using Apple Configuration (https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/apple-configurator/id434433123?mt=12)

There is a library /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib. It has API AXSGuidedAccessEnabled(); I didn't use it, but I assume it will return whether device is in accessibility mode.